# Adicionar Objeto Array Subdocumento Reactjs e Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, react, jsx

**Senhores**,

Por gentileza, podem me ajudar com esta duvida?

**Resumo**: Estou criando um mini app utilizando node/mongo/react. Este app utiliza relacionamento no Mongo e gostaria de ajuda **para adicionar dados via frontend(reactjs) para o array no mongo.**

No backend funciona perfeitamente, não estou conseguindo montar, veja o código.

**Codigo**

Model: CLIENTE

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const ClientSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },

    trainings: [{
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Training'
    }]
},
    {
        timestamps: true
    })
const Client = mongoose.model('Client', ClientSchema)
module.exports = Client
```

MODEL : TRAINING

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const TrainingSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
      ref: "Client",
      require: true
    },
    nameTrainer: {
      type: String
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
const Training = mongoose.model("Training", TrainingSchema);
module.exports = Training;
```

---

Gostaria de **inserir/adicionar** varios trainings (que está no model cliente) em REACT.

Meu código em REACT.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Trainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChangeNameTrainer = this.handleChangeNameTrainer.bind(this);

    this.handleOnSubmitTrainer = this.handleOnSubmitTrainer.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      clients: []
    };
  }


  handleChangeNameTrainer(e) {
    this.setState({
      nameTrainer: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleOnSubmitTrainer(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const objtrainer = [
      {
        nameTrainer: this.state.nameTrainer,
        nameExercicie: this.state.nameExercicie,

      }
    ];
    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:4000/u/add/" + this.props.match.params.id,
        objtrainer
      )
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error.res));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ maginTop: 10 }}>
        <br />
        <h3>
          Novo Treino de: {this.state.name} {this.state.last_name}
        </h3>
        <br />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
          <div className="form-row">
            <div className="form-group col-md-8 center">
              <label>Nome do Treino:</label>
              <div className="input-group">
                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                  <div className="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                    <i className="far fa-user" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control border-left-0 border"
                  value={this.state.nameTrainer}
                  onChange={this.handleChangeNameTrainer}
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">
              Adicionar
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Resumindo ... 
Gostaria que de uma ajuda de voces ...

Abaixo, segue retorno que gostaria em react ...
Adicionar um novo treino ...

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c8fb4ce37a289357c6c4753"
    },
    "trainings": [
       {
          nameTrainer: "Ombro"
 }
 ],
    "name": "Alice",
}
```

---